# SecureString from WPF's PasswordBox is different than manually built one

Tags: c#, wpf, encryption

I have two apps:

1. a WPF app that captures a password via PasswordBox element and encrypts a C# string using it, and
2. an ASP.NET app that receives the same password via configuration in plaintext and uses it to decrypt the string from #1.

The WPF app is able to decrypt the string just fine, while the ASP.NET app isn't. I've made sure that plaintexts and salts used in encryption/decryption in both apps are the same.

Here's the relevant code, which is shared by both apps:

```
string Encrypt(string value, SecureString password, string salt)
{
    var temp = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(password);
    var lengthInBytes = Marshal.SizeOf(temp);

    // The rest of the encryption code...
}

string Decrypt(string value, SecureString password, string salt)
{
    var temp = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(password);
    var lengthInBytes = Marshal.SizeOf(temp);

    // The rest of the decryption code...
}
```

There's no mistake here: the shown lines in both functions are indeed the same, as they, IMHO, should be.

And yet, the `lengthInBytes` variable inside the `Decrypt` differs between apps. It equals 8 under ASP.NET (where it fails to decrypt) and 4 under WPF (where both functions work correctly). The test password plaintext was "test", if that matters.

The reason I'm not showing the rest of the code is because it doesn't really matter. It's obvious to me it can't possibly work while this difference exists, so this is what I'm focusing on.

The WPF app captures the `SecureString` directly from the `PasswordBox.SecurePassword` property. OTOH, the ASP.NET builds it by calling `AppendChar` in a loop on a fresh `SecureString` instance. I'm aware this isn't as secure, but there wasn't any viable non-interactive alternative for this scenario. While this is beside the point, I suspect it may be a part of the problem. I just don't see how, yet.

What have I missed?

FWIW, the WPF app is currently employing the `Obfuscar` tool on its entry executable. I didn't yet try to disable this to see if it made any difference.

**UPDATE**: Here's the code I'm using on the ASP.NET side to create a `SecureString` from a plaintext `System.String`:

```
using (var secure = new SecureString())
{
    for (var i = 0; i < plaintext.Length; i++)
    {
        secure.AppendChar(plaintext[i]);
    }

    return Decrypt(encrypted, secure, salt);
}
```

Comment: Unicode is 2 bytes length per char, "test" has 4 letters, do the math...

Comment: My understanding is that "test" contains 4 chars in WPF as well as ASP.NET. Am I wrong? So why the difference?

Comment: You are, SizeOf returns the length in bytes of the object, if the string is encoded in unicode it will return 8 bytes. Also, a bad encoding transfer may have been used (transferred the content as UTF8 while it really was Unicode) so it's just a matter of wrong encoding when transferring the data to the server.

Comment: But... but... I WANT to support Unicode in passwords! So the 8 bytes, as they are in ASP.NET, are perfectly fine with me. The problem then becomes: why does the PasswordBox in WPF give me 4 bytes? And more importantly, how can I influence that so that it becomes 8 as well?

Comment: Have you checked the received data? Do you read "test" on the page or you can see something like "t e s t "?

Comment: Also, using a binary string for the encription/decription is not very wise, on each machine you can have different results based on the default encoding used on the machine. Why do you need to get the binary string? Is a requirement of your enc/dec code?

Comment: @Gusman: I'll amend my question with some more code. But in essence, I receive an instance of System.String with 4 characters: "test", as I should be. When I then build a SecureString from that (please, see the additional code in my question in a couple of minutes), the final length is 8. Not so when using PasswordBox, though! As for your second question, the requirement isn't about using "binary strings", at all! It's just that I need to get exact same byte array from either a plaintext I received from server configuration or from a SecureString, captured via PasswordBox on the client.

Comment: So, you receive a plain string, load that content into a regular string, then you use that string to create a SecureString... that defeats the entire purpose of SecureString, you can remove it from your code and will be exactly equal secure... If you want the exact same binary array, use plain Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes() and will behave the same on any machine independently of the default encoding for the system.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of that, as I've said in the question already. The fact is, I simply don't care on the ASP.NET side, because there are multiple levels of security before it gets to the point of use. I DO care on the WPF side, though! So that's why I use PasswordBox there and NEVER decode the SecureString into System.String inside that app. And therein lies the problem: in the end I must have a byte[], and I have to obtain the bytes in different ways on both ends (from plaintext on ASP.NET side and from PasswordBox on WPF side). Using GetBytes in the WPF app would require having plaintext!

Comment: On the app side you can use `Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode`, that will return a pointer to the Unicode string ensuring it will be the same on any system, on the asp .net side skip the SecureString and go with `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()`.

Comment: Ok, after reviewing the code again I realized that you're using `Marshal.SizeOf` over an IntPtr, not the string... that will return the size of the `IntPtr`... Are you testing on a 32 bit machine the WPF app and on a 64 bit machine the ASP .NET? Anyways, in any case it's wrong, you can't use `Marshal.SizeOf` to get the size.

Comment: To add to what @Gusman wrote, you can't use `Marshal.SizeOf` on `SecureString` directly either, because `SecureString` doesn't have sequential or explicit layout.

Comment: @Gusman: Ok, now we're getting somewhere! I'll change the code from SecureStringToBSTR to SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode and try again. FWIW, I'm testing on the same machine, running in two different types of apps (ASP.NET under IIS Express, built for Any CPU and configured to use 64-bit IIS Express and WPF built for x64 target). I admit I may be misunderstanding the purpose of Marshal.SizeOf, but AFAIU the docs say it should return the size of the underlying structure when I pass an IntPtr. I wasn't aware that was a wrong interpretation.

Comment: @Gusman: You were completely right! I should've been using Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode and allocating the byte arrays using a predictable length * sizeof(char) formula instead of messing with Marshal.SizeOf and BSTRs. Please post your answer so I can accept it! And, of course, thank you! :)

Comment: The difference then should be you're compiling the WPF app as "Any CPU" and you have the "Prefer 32 bit" option checked in the config, thus the WPF app is running at 32 bits, while your ASP .Net is running at real 64 bits.

Comment: @Gusman: Correct again, as it turns out. I forgot about this option, which seems to override the x64 configuration target and enforce 32 bits. However, please see my comment on your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incorrectly using `Marshal.SizeOf` to try to get the string length but that will return the `IntPtr` structure size. Also, I would recommend to use unicode encoding to avoid any change on the data because of the system's encoding:

```
string Encrypt(string value, SecureString password, string salt)
{
    try
    {

        var temp = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(password);
        var lengthInBytes = sizeof(char) * password.Length;

        // The rest of the encription code...
    }
    finally
    {
        //Cleanup
        Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(temp);
    }
}

string Decrypt(string value, SecureString password, string salt)
{

    try
    {

        var temp = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(password);
        var lengthInBytes = sizeof(char) * password.Length;

        // The rest of the decryption code...
    }
    finally
    {
        //Cleanup
        Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(temp);
    }
}
```

Always remember to zero the memory and free it or the SecureString purpose will be defeated.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, again! :)

Comment: As per your last comment on my question, I did a test and it turns out that Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char)) returns 1 in my configuration, while sizeof(char) returns 2. Consequently, I had to change the code to use the sizeof(char) or I'd again allocate only half the required buffer. Please, comment further, if you see fit!

Comment: EDIT: Scratch this my last comment, if you've seen it. It's been a long day and I'm starting to hallucinate. All is well. Cheers! :)

The previous comment still stands, though!

Comment: Well, it's very strange, it should return the same according to the documentation of both functions, but I think it's not really well explained `sizeof(char)` returns the size of the unmanaged type `char` and `Marshal.SizeOf` returns the size of the managed char in unicode.